# Root cern root-system on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: apt, 16.10, source-packages

The package root-system is available to install by using "apt" for Ubuntu 16.04

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=root-system&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all

Nevertheless on Ubuntu 16.10 it is not available, as can be verified from the package search for a specific ubuntu distribution, which for this question is "yakkety"  http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Is there a ppa or something else that I can use in order to be able to install root-system on Ubuntu 16.10 by using "apt"?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a PPA that works for Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Launchpad Source Package Page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/root-system), the package does not exist in Yakkety or later.

As such, `root-system` is not installable by default.  You are welcome to download the Xenial packages and try to use those, however you should keep in mind ***that the package in question was dropped in Debian first***, for the following reasons (Italics indicate something I added for clarity, and bold indicates important points which I want to emphasize; neither are part of the original bug report in Debian):

> Dear FTP masters,
>
> Please remove src:root-system and its binaries from the archive. ROOT is a huge beast to maintain, and **it's currently not maintained**:
>
> - We have a quite ancient release,
> - It's FTBFS *(Failing to build from source)* with newer libraries (as it's not keeping up with transition, and it's entangled in several of them),
> - At the moment it has 3 RC bugs, oldest one being more than one year   old about it FTBFSing with GCC-5.
>
> (source: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=827248)

Given these, I don't think it's wise to continue to try and use it, especially since there will be potential build errors with the newer libraries that come in Yakkety and beyond.  It was dropped in Ubuntu because it was removed in Debian (you can see this by expanding the latest entry [on the full publishing history on Launchpad, which points to the aforementioned Debian bug as the source reason](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/root-system/+publishinghistory))

Note that these fail-to-build problems here may also explain why there are no PPAs that contain the `root-system` packages.

Comment: Thank for the very complete information of the status of root-system. However I need to install the program and I would prefer not to do it manually, because I think that upgrading and removing won't be easy.  I did something that probably is not good idea, which was to add the ppa deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe

Comment: Once I install the program I remove the ppa and I have noted that now I can remove the program by using apt. However I am not feeling comfortable with that solution. Would it be better to unistall the program and try to install it manually?